# Override TextView ellipsize char('...') with ("... Read more")

Tags: android, textview, android-view

I want to replace the char ('...') with a string ("...Read more").
Any easy way to do that by extending TextView and overriding a property?
I am expanding the TextView on click by increasing lines from 2 to 500 and vice versa. The TextView is in a ScrollView.

Comment: Are you ellipsizing your textview? And you want to replace or override that ellipsized string on the end as "..."?

Comment: Yes, I am ellipsizing it. And it is all correct. The problem is that I want to add "Read more" after the ellipsizing or to be part of it.

Comment: Checkout the answer, I think it is all what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/19676336/3819836

Comment: If I was going for an overcomplicated solution, I would implement my own custom view. The thing is that I really think there might be a simple solution that doesn't involve Layout observers, clickable spannables,...etc.
@HassanJamil

Comment: Yeah, it is overcomplicated as per your requirements, I think you will not find any other simpler solution than this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18738234/3819836