# Textview three dots when text truncates but also include the ending quote

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, textview, spannable

I have a textview with the property

`android:maxLines="1"`

In case the text is too long it truncates and add the three dots. i.e

If I want to put the text (including the quotes) 
"hello world one two three four"

It will display

"hello world one two....

but I would like to display the closing quote.

"hello world one two..."

How to achieve this??

Comment: You have to do it with two textViews only I guess. One with the truncated one and at the end text view with the quote.

Comment: detecting if textview is ellipsized might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005933/how-do-i-tell-if-my-textview-has-been-ellipsized

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_tv_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    />
```

And in your activity,

```
val stringText = "hello world one two three four"
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.activity_main_tv_text).text = String.format("\"%s\"", stringText)
```

[image]

Comment: The string is not a constant

Comment: This is how you can do it dynamically.

Comment: This is a very simple solution to what you need here.

Comment: I tried but did not work.

Comment: Really! for me, it worked in one go. May I know what issue you are facing?

Comment: So the issue here is that the text should be long enough to show the there dots "hello world one two three...", you are just assigning a string with a particular format.

Comment: Okay, so you wanted quotes and ellipsize end's 3 dots if the text is long.

Comment: I think Biraj's answer here is the correct way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738050/textview-add-text-after-ellipsis-or-change-ellipsis-character?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Biraj's answer helped a bit but the way I ended up doing is by using textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener to see if the text was Ellipsized, then I calculated the indexes of what using the layout and getEllipsisCount to know what was the end of the original string that was being cut, and I created a new string manually using the three dots and the quotes at the end