# Change ellipsize character

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

How can I change dots to commas/stars when using ellipsize (textview) in Android?

Example with dots: Lorem Ipsum is simply dum...

Example with stars: Lorem Ipsum is simply dum***

Comment: Are you interested in how to change in dynamically?

Comment: Any way.. I can't find solution.

Comment: `s = s.replace("\u22EF", "***");`  or `s = s.replace("...", "***");`; everything else is hard.

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738234/9946202

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The ellipsis strings are hardcoded in the platform [`TextUtils`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java;l=94) and [`StaticLayout`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/StaticLayout.java) is where ellipsizing happens. Obtaining the text content from a `TextView` does not come with the ellipsis chars in place.

In theory you could cook up your own ellipsizer that modifies the string to truncate the way you want before passing it to `TextView`.

Comment: Right. But a custom library can do the task 

Comment: Yes, that's someone else cooking up the ellipsizer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/TheCodeYard/EllipsizedTextView) library by `TheCodeYard`. You can use all the ellipse types with a custom ellipse text. This is a sample image of that library:

[image]